# Can I install just the Unity desktop on top of another distro?

Tags: package-management

I'm wondering whether it is possible to take any distro other than Ubuntu (and its derivatives) and put Unity/Ubuntu-HUD on top of it, just like you would for instance install LXDE onto any distro that came with a different desktop that you didn't like?
I have done

```
 apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

on my machine running Bodhi Linux,
but practically got it transformed into Ubuntu, that install pulling all of the Ubuntu apps automatically.
What I wanted though was to use only the applications I had, in a different GUI.
Is this possible, and if yes, how?
Thanks, Ben

Comment: You can install Unity on top of any distro.  There are tutorials on the web doing it for Arch and a couple other distros.

Comment: @mateo_salta - I would council against getting started with unity-2d since it's going to be unmaintained in the immediate future.

Comment: @aking1012 `unity-2d` is present in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, which means it will be maintained with security updates (and some stability updates) until April 2017.

Comment: @EliahKagan I was referring to this: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTA5OTA it goes away in 12.10.  So unless you are sticking with LTS, it should be removed in a couple of days (October 12.10 stable release)

Comment: @aking1012 Indeed, but I suspect this will not affect anyone's ability to install Unity 2D in non-Ubuntu operating systems. Though I suppose people packaging it might stop, and start packaging Unity to use llvmpipe instead, as in Quantal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm wondering whether it is possible to take any distro other than Ubuntu (and its derivatives) and put Unity/Ubuntu-HUD on top of it, just like you would for instance install LXDE onto any distro that came with a different desktop that you didn't like?

Yes, just install Unity *not*  the full `ubuntu-desktop` meta package.

> I have done apt-get install ubuntu-desktop on my machine running Bodhi Linux, but practically got it transformed into Ubuntu, that install pulling all of the Ubuntu apps automatically.

Because you basically installed the default configuration for Ubuntu. For example, Installing `lxde`is not the same as Installing `lubuntu-desktop`.

> What I wanted though was to use only the applications I had, in a different GUI. Is this possible, and if yes, how?

Just install `unity` with the suffix `--no-install-recommends`

Answer (score 2):

Bodhi Linux is just Ubuntu with another desktop (E17). It's a derivative just as Xubuntu or Lubuntu. So in your case you could just install the *unity* package.

If you want to install Unity on a distribution that is not Ubuntu, you run into problems. Unity needs changes in some Gnome libraries, that Gnome refused to accept. So these changes didn't make it into other distributions.

There are effords to offer Unity for OpenSuse and Fedora (google it), but they obviously have to also offer the Gnome libraries which is a bad idea in the first place (i.e. using a 3rd party repository that changes core libs).