# Installing Unity on a 13.04 mini install without other packages

Tags: installation, unity, 13.04, package-management, ubuntu-minimal

I'm installing using [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD).  It's the mini version of Ubuntu designed to be built as you go along, and it doesn't come with a GUI. I have tried to install Unity, but it comes with many other packages I don't want, such as Thunderbolt and Libre Office. Is there a way to just install Unity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can i install just the unity desktop on top of another distro](http://askubuntu.com/questions/193847/can-i-install-just-the-unity-desktop-on-top-of-another-distro)?

Comment: This is actually a good response. Thank you.  I've looked through that thread and found what the difference between "ubuntu-desktop" and "unity" is.  I'm not entirely sure what else comes with unity, but I suppose I will find out.  I'm still open to other responses however

Answer (score 1):

The dependencies for *Unity* are listed on this [page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/ubuntu-desktop) for the *ubuntu-desktop* package. Dependencies can be circumvented during installation with these commands:

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install
```

or

```
sudo aptitude --without-recommends install
```

Although, these will end up installing some recommends; *apt-get* installing the most dependencies it seems. You can find a reference on *--no-install-recommends* [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65081/implications-of-no-install-recommends-apt-get-install).